# UIImagePickerController, when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not implemented

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

A quick conceptual question,

If I am using UIImagePickerController, and I don't implement didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, or attempt to handle the returned UIImage after a picture is "taken", what happens to the UIImage data that would have been returned during the delegate call, is it just released by the system?

After testing it doesn't seem to leak or get added to the standard Photos library.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it would leak in the first place.

You gotta think that the code that the Apple developers wrote already makes sure to release the image that the camera took once the delegate call has been completed. For example, let's pretend that this is what the developer's could looks like (pre-ARC, to show you that you don't even need ARC to have this).

```
- (IBAction)userDidPressAccept:(id)sender
{
    // Obtain image from wherever it came from, this image will start with
    // Retain Count: 1
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init]; 

    // Build an NSDictionary, and add the image in
    // Image Retain Count: 2
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:image, UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, ..., nil];

    // Now the dictionary has ownership of the image, we can safely release it
    // Image Retain Count: 1
    [image release];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)])
    {
        // Guy sees what he does with his image
        // Image Retain Count: X (Depends on the user)
        [self.delegate imagePickerController:self didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:image];
    }

    // Ok, we're done. Dictionary gets released, and it can no longer own the image
    // Image Retain Count: X-1 (Depends on the user)
    [userInfo release];
}
```

In the example, if user did not `retain` the image (or didn't even implement the method), then X will be 1, and when it gets to the final `release`, the image will be gone for good. If the user does retain the image, then the image will live on, but the dictionary that supported it can get `dealloc`-ated.

This is the basic concept of "ownership" that comes with reference counting, it's like a glass ball that needs to be passed hand by hand, and if the ball has no hand under it, it will fall and break.

ARC kinda masks all this by doing it itself, but the basic concepts remains, the ownership is transferred to the delegate's implementation, and if there's no delegate that claims it, it will get deleted.