# using input tag in a form for IOS - does it save the image on the device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, input, buffer

using the following on iphone

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

this allows the user to take an image using the native camera. It then  sends the image to the form for uploading.

It seems that the image is not saved into the camera role which is good. We need to be 100% satisfied that the image is not saved anywhere on the phone itself or the buffer.

So the question is :Is the image that was taken using the above code stored anywhere on the phone or buffer and if so what are the steps to retrieving it.

ie. jailbreak / hacking

Answer (score 1):

See this question, that I asked: [UIImagePickerController, when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740058/uiimagepickercontroller-when-didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-not-implemented)

The image is not retained. Your tag will invoke the same methods.

You cannot retrieve the image.